# can I reply html file as response with cpprest?

Tags: html, c++, http, cpprest-sdk

I'm using cpprest for  small http web service

When request from client comes, I want to make server reply response as html file.

like :

```
//Webserver.cpp

...

void HandleGet(http_request request)
{
    uri relativeUri = request.relative_uri();
    utility::string_t path = relativeUri.path();

    ... some work ...

    //set response instance
    http_response response(status_codes::OK);
    response.headers().add(U("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"), U("*"));
    response.headers().set_content_type(L"text/html");

    response.set_body( ***** );    // maybe html file contents be here

    request.reply(response);
}
```

And one more..

If that idea works, where will html file exists in?

Same directory that cpp file exists?

Please help me..

Comment: the html will be sent to the client, you are not saving it locally.

Answer (score 0):

the html will be sent to the client, you are not saving it locally.

Comment: well.. when I type `127.0.0.1:8080/index.html` in web browser, I think server app should reply the contents of `index.html`. so don't server have the file `index.html` somewhere?

Comment: no, the content is generated by the server. no need to actual index.html file to be created. just go to 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: what if I want to add custom contents in `index.html`?(like link to other pages, some images, .. so on) how can the server generate it?

Comment: You answered it yourself...    response.set_body( ***** );    // maybe html file contents be here

Comment: then.. could you tell me how to get contents of html file? I'm thinking of using `ifstream` to read file, but I think it's not that graceful idea..